# BlackBerry Push Notification Sent Successfully but not received in device

Tags: push-notification, blackberry-10

I am implementing push notification in Android ported BB 10 app. I am using Push Sharp in sevrer side to send notification. Below is my code:

```
bbBroker.QueueNotification(new BlackberryNotification
                                {
                                    Recipients = new List<BlackberryRecipient> { bbReceipent },
                                    Content = new BlackberryMessageContent(json),
                                    SourceReference = "myappid"
                                });

                                bbBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) =>
                                {
                                    Log.WriteLog("BBB Notification Sent Successfully");
                                };
```

`OnNotificationSucceeded` is called, but in my device I don't see any notification.

One time I heard only sound and red color icon on my app. I was not aware how to view notification, I uninstalled the app, then again installed it. Then I pushed some text, but now even sound also stopped coming.

Please someone guide me what is going on?

Comment: I just restarted the device and push notification started coming :)

Comment: Hi,could u plz suggest me the push notification library(not urban airship) for blackberry app(written in c++)??

Comment: I don;t know BB much. I just implemented push notification in Android converted ported BB app by following [this](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html) doc.